# changing Widget Text through JSNI

Tags: javascript, gwt, element, jsni

Hi I am using JSNI in  GWT to use some javascript code. I have my widgets defined in uibinder(file.ui.xml) :

```
 <g:Label ui:field="LBLMsg" text="mytext" styleName="{style.conceptMessage}" width="1800px"/>
```

than i used this Label in my java file through following code:

@UiField Label LBLMsg;

it is working fine i can use label widget and can change the text using LBLMsg.setText("sometex")
however my problem starts when i pass it in to my JSNI function to used it in some JAVAScript code. i wish to change the text of this label using Java script for this i used following code:

```
 void TestWritingLabelFromJSNI()
      {
        writeGWTLabel(LBLMsg.getElement());

        }   
    private native void writeGWTLabel(Element elt)/*-{

    var labelelement = document.getElementById('LBLMsg');
    alert("Element labelelement ;"+labelelement );

        }-*/
```

when i call this the labelelement return null. and hence i cannot set it text. I am not sure what i am doing . can anybody suggest any thing. really appreciate any help. already wast too much time without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
private native void writeGWTLabel(Element elem, String text)/*-{
    // Remove all children first.
    while (elem.firstChild) {
      elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
    }
    // Add a new text node.
    if (text != null) {
      elem.appendChild(elem.ownerDocument.createTextNode(text));
    }
}-*/
```

Comment: i had tried it but it did not work. with following error:
Uncaught com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : elt_0_g$.setInnerText is not a function

Comment: thanks .it worked for me. However It added the text not in the label widget but to the added node. i wish to add the the text in the label widget that i passed to the jsni. the innertext does not work any advice on it.

Comment: When you call label.setText(""), this native method is called under the hood.

Comment: thanks. i checked it again  i was passing reference of another widget next to label. it is now perfecting working .btw can we also change the position of widget in jsni  ,like if want to change the position of this label